# How to display zero values in matrix report for grand total

Tags: reporting, matrix

I have a  matrix report where salesforce is ignoring the grand total for 0 values. How can I display the 0 values in grand total.Currently the report is grouped by created date.

Please help![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuDIN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to load a dummy record for each month's period you want to have represented on the report.

*You need to enable [Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-specify-the-values-in-Created-By-Created-Date-Last-Modified-By-ID-Last-Modified-Date&language=en_US) for the user's profile that will do this data load.

Comment: hi @Oleksiy : Can you please elaborate I didnot understand

Comment: Is there any other way we can display zero values

Comment: Do you mean that not all 'Created By' users shown on the report? Well, this is an expected functionality - report are using records returned after all filters are applied. You will need to figure out what other filter(s) to add to include all dummy records that can return all list of users you want to have on the report.

Comment: Hi @Oleksiy : Actually the report is based on a particular profile. Can I show zero values on graphs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom report type using a `User` as a primary object, and `Activity Relationships`. Then filter by Activity `Created Date`, User `Profile Name`, and any additional filters to make sure you are only looking at Activities related to the object(s) you are interested
[image]